# I am not able to click on the specific element in selenium

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver

Here I am trying to click on the pathway program link from the admission drop down but it does not click on the it.
I have used for loop to retrieve the elements and i am to get the list of elements but now i am not able to click on the specific element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRIen.png)

```
package class1;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class parulUniversity {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\A0885643\\Desktop\\Selenium-Java\\Day1\\DriverWeb1\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://paruluniversity.ac.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement Admissions = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Admissions']"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        action.moveToElement(Admissions).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sub-sub-menu']"));
        for(int i = 0;i<options.size();i++) {
            
            WebElement element = options.get(i);
            String elementText = element.getText();
            System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
            
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            if(elementText.equals("Pathway Programs")) {                    
                element.click();
                
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: I think if you check the homepage it shows a list when we move the mouse on the Admission, and after we click on any name the view is changed we need to click on the Admission then it shows the dropdown. So if you provide more details on how you want to click on the specific link i.e by mouse over or by click.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below refactored code. I have removed `Thread.sleep` and used Selenium's [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) which are more effective and fast.

Below code will mouse-hover <kbd>Admissions</kbd> menu and then click on <kbd>Pathway Programs</kbd> sub-menu.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://paruluniversity.ac.in/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
WebElement Admissions = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Admissions']")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(Admissions).build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Pathway Programs']"))).click();
```

**UPDATE** If you still want to continue with your approach/code, then note that the issue is in the XPath expression of below line:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sub-sub-menu']"));
```

Change the XPath expression to: `(//ul[@class='sub-sub-menu'])[4]//li`, so that the desired element is located.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//ul[@class='sub-sub-menu'])[4]//li"));
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but I am looking for the logic used in my for loop code

Comment: Thankyou but i want to use my for loop logic only can't this be done using for loop logic which i have written?

Comment: Yes you can use your for loop logic. Just check my updated answer, change the XPath expression as I have mentioned. Ensure you use //li at the end

Comment: This Xpath which you gave is not working & also this cannot be detected in the Web Browser as well